# `useAuthRequest` always returns `dismiss`

Tags: react-native, expo

1. SDK Version: 37
2. Platforms(Android/iOS/web/all): Android (Expo Client)

I’m using `useAuthRequest` from `expo-auth-session` to fetch an authentication code for itsme, a Belgian OpenID Connect authentication provider. I'm using the Expo client on Android.

The code looks like this:

```js
export default function SignUpScreen() {
  const discovery = useAutoDiscovery('https://e2emerchant.itsme.be/oidc');
  const [request, response, promptAsync] = useAuthRequest(
    {
      clientId: Itsme.CLIENT_ID,
      redirectUri: makeRedirectUri(),
      scopes: [
        'openid',
        'service:CURVO_TEST_SHAREDATA',
        'profile',
        'email',
        'phone',
        'address'
      ],
      extraParams: {
        claims: JSON.stringify({
          userinfo: {
            'tag:sixdots.be,2016-06:claim_nationality': null,
            'tag:sixdots.be,2016-06:claim_city_of_birth': null,
            'tag:sixdots.be,2016-06:claim_eid': null,
            'tag:sixdots.be,2017-05:claim_photo': null
          }
        })
      }
    },
    discovery
  );

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={promptAsync}>Log in</TouchableOpacity>
  );
```

When the “Log in” button is pressed, the following happens:

1. (OK) The itsme application is correctly opened. I can tell that the scopes have also been correctly communicated.
2. (OK) I can authenticate within the itsme application with my itsme PIN code.
3. (OK) The itsme application then closes, which is expected.
4. (OK) My app is re-opened.
5. (NOT OK) The `response` variable becomes equal to `{ type: 'dismiss' }`.

Whatever I do, the response is always “dismiss”. I find it strange because the [docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/auth-session/#returns-4) say:

> If the authentication is dismissed manually with AuthSession.dismiss() , the result is { type: 'dismiss' } .

However, I never call `AuthSession.dismiss()`.

It looks like it’s failing right at the last step, when it’s supposed to parse the authorization code out of the response URL.

I tried several things:

- starting Expo in all three modes: tunnel, lan, localhost
- adding a path to the redirect URI, like `makeRedirectUri({ path: '/itsme' })`
- the `AppState.currentState` “trick” described in a (related?) [GitHub issue](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/6679#issuecomment-570963717).

None of these tries worked and I’m out of ideas. Any thoughts or suggestions? Or maybe how to debug inside `expo-auth-session to see what’s going on?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a resolution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet :(